# Unit Testing with Microsoft Fakes in Windows Runtime Library

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, windows-runtime

Is there a way to use Microsoft Fakes Shims for Windows Runtime APIs? I am trying to unit test an application and need to isolate the code from some Windows Runtime APIs.

[This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441482.aspx) implies you can use Microsoft Fakes with Store Apps. However, if I create a store app, I do not see the option "Add Fakes Assembly" in the shortcut menu for the "Windows" reference. I am using VS Ultimate 2013.